# Button Displays Under Cells in Custom UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, ios5, uitableview, interface-builder

I have an app that uses a custom `UITableViewCell` to display detail information after a user clicks on a given row in a table.  I can't seem to figure out why the "Reply" button located in the cell is inactive and appears behind the table itself.  I can't click on it, select it, or do anything.  I used Interface Builder to add the button rather than programmatically add it.

I've tried changing a number of things including the cell's class and File's Owner, but can't seem to get the button to be active and working.  I think the button is linked up properly with a connection to a method in the code.

[image: UIButton under table]

Here's a minimal, complete example of the code:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/atcof58ciqbaojr/CustomCell.zip

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently I needed to tell the table view how high the cell was.  This is what fixed it:

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;
{
    return 157.0;
}
```